# Как получить значение поля в joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

Пытаюсь сделать проверку на совпадение по телефону в компоненте joomshop, никак не пойму как получить переменную которая должна проверяться.
Функция которая проверяет существует ли такой пользователь:

```
    function check_user_exist_ajax() {
    $mes = array();
    $username = JRequest::getVar("username");
    $email = JRequest::getVar("email");
    $mobil_phone = JRequest::getVar("mobil_phone");
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    /* $mes[] = sprintf(_JSHOP_USER_EXIST_EMAIL, $mobil_phone); */
    if (isset($mobil_phone)){
        $query = "SELECT id FROM `#__jshopping_users` WHERE mobil_phone = '".$mobil_phone."'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
        if ($db->getNumRows()){ 
            $mes[] = sprintf(_JSHOP_USER_EXIST_EMAIL, $mobil_phone);
        } 
    }
    if ($username){
        $query = "SELECT id FROM `#__users` WHERE username = '".$db->escape($username)."'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
        if ($db->getNumRows()){ 
            $mes[] = sprintf(_JSHOP_USER_EXIST, $username);
        }
    }
    if ($email){
        $query = "SELECT id FROM `#__users` WHERE email = '".$db->escape($email). "'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
        if ($db->getNumRows()){ 
            $mes[] = sprintf(_JSHOP_USER_EXIST_EMAIL, $email);
        }
    }

    if (count($mes)==0){
        print "1";
    }else{
        print implode("\n",$mes);
    }
    die();
}
```

Не могу получить номер телефона $mobil_phone = JRequest::getVar("mobil_phone");
Возвращает пустое поле. Объясните как получает данные функция JRequest::getVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRequest устаревший класс!

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; // объект JInput

$mobil_phone = $input->getString('mobil_phone'); // в классе JInput есть методы для получения конкретных типов данных, в этом случае мы получаем строку

$method = $input->getMethod(); // так мы можем получить метод по которому был отправлен запрос на сервер 

$mobil_phone = $input->$method->getString('mobil_phone'); // так получаем данные из метода по которому был отправлен запрос на сервер, вместо $method мы можем указать непосредственно сам метод get, post и тп
```

в основном все поля формы в джумле группируются в jform, то есть имя поля будет  jform[mobil_phone]

и вот для того, что бы получить значения этого поля, нужно изначально получить массив jform, а потом нужный элемент по ключу

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $input->get('jform', array(), 'array');

// $data['mobil_phone'] // это и будет значения нашего поля
```

Comment: Там как раз старая версия, в общем разобрался, проблема была в том, что я не знал как передаются эти переменные контроллеру, JS файл был минифицирован, поэтому было сложно понять что все передавалось через AJAX